# An easy way to reorder many template groups at once

Tags: templates, groups, orders, template-manager

I'm wondering if there's an easier way to re-order template groups on the template manager screen, something that's easier to do in bulk than clicking and dragging one at a time.

Thanks.

Comment: By easier, I should say.. like an add-on, or a screen that lets you reorder them by number the way it used to work (not that the current drag-and-drop system is bad for quick re-ordering of a few groups...)

Comment: I actually never knew you could drag and drop template groups! How did I never try that??

Answer (score 2):

If you have an SQL editor, like Sequel Pro, that allows you to quickly edit data in SQL tables, the `group_order` column in the `exp_template_groups` table is where the order is stored.

You can see the data with:

```
select * from exp_template_groups
```

Fancy SQL to renumber the groups to match the ID order, or alphabetical order, also might be doable.